# CORS запрещает запрос к Яндекс Кассе

Tags: javascript, rest, axios, cors

Пытаюсь создать запрос на создание платежа к Яндекс Кассе.
При отправке запроса в консоль выводится ошибка:
[image: ошибка в консоли браузера]

Вот мой код:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом в REST клиенте Insomnia запрос корректно обрабатывается. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Заголовок Access-control-allow-origin должен выставлять сам яндекс, а не вы. Раз он его не выставляет, значит яндекс не позволяет использовать свой api в ajax

Comment: Что то мне подсказывает, что данный api предназначен для выполнения со стороны вашего сервера, а не на клиенте. По карйней мере в api выполняемом на клиенте не может быть secret_key, он не должен использоваться  нигде кроме как на сервере